# Having a forked repo, and a separate repo being able to update from a certain folder inside the forked repo

Tags: github, git

I'd like to know, if this is possible.

The thing is, i forked yiiframework to my repo. As I understand, this will keep my repo automaticly updated?

Then I have my develop-repo which only wants a certain folder inside my forked repo fx the "framework" folder, and want's to be able to update FROM that certain folder on request. 
Do I then create an upstream to that certain folder, or have I misunderstood that?

I'm using git from the terminal.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure if what you want is possible, but my theory is that if you can somehow add the fork as a submodule, you would be able to achieve what you want.

Help on forking: http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Help on submodules: http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

Comment: Awesome. It solved my problem halfish. But I found a workaround using upstream :)